# Select Sort Algorithm in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, sorting

I am studying data structures and algorithms and I defined the function [below] to implement the **Select Sort Algorithm**.... However, the statement for switching minimum values to the beginning of the array doesn't seem to be working. Here is the function definition:

```
def selectionSort(array: list):
    array_length = len(array)  # this just stores the length of the given list
    _index = 0  # this takes care of dynamically changing the index in which a minimum value is to be found

    for i in array:
        min_value = min(array[_index:array_length])
        if i == min_value:  # if i is the minimum value then do nothing, however update _index
            _index += 1
            continue
        else:  # if i is not the minimum value.... 
            array[_index], array[array.index(min_value)] = min_value, i  # replace i with the minimum number, and move i to the [now previous] position of the minimum number,
            _index += 1  # don'f forget to update _index
    return array
```

The particular command `array[_index], array[array.index(min_value)] = min_value, i` doesn't seem to be working and it actually is responsible for switching the position of the minimum value in the array `min_value` with the currently evaluated value in the array `i` {if `i` is not the minimum number `min_number`}

I have tried testing this function with this array (or `list` as it is called in python):

```
[5, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7]
```

With failed results as the function return the same array that was entered. The reason why I am doing this is that I am trying to see if it is possible to implement a Select Sort algorithm without implementing 2 `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
array[_index], array[array.index(min_value)] = min_value, i
```

is the same as:

```
temp = (min_value, i)
array[_index] = temp[0]
array[array.index(min_value)] = temp[1]
```

First, `array[_index]` is set to `min_value`. This means (if not the same minimum value is in a prior index in array) that the following `array.index(min_value)` returns `_index`.

Simple solution: Swap expressions:

```
array[array.index(min_value)], array[_index] = i, min_value
```